# "/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" error with Virtualbox

Tags: 11.10, ecryptfs

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday in VirtualBox 4.1.4 and every time I boot Ubuntu it says:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present
```

I've done a fair bit of Googling to try to figure out how to fix this but have come up empty. It appears that the swap is not being mounted, I don't see it listed when I type the mount command and look at the list of mounted devices.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Apparently it is mounting swap. I just checked dmesg. Perhaps the message is not really an error but a timing thing that corrects itself during the boot?

```
Adding 1046524k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1046524k
```

Comment: i'm getting this on a fresh install of ubuntu 12.10. also, what is weird, it shows me the message on the splash screen with an option to skip or fix manually... but dmesg does not have a single line regarding it!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to check to see if swap is mounted is with `free`. To manually correct this problem, do `sudo swapon -a`, which will tell the system "start swapping on ALL of the pre-configured swap areas"

Comment: Thanks for answering. Apparently swap was being mounted all along. I should have checked dmesg prior to posting but I was fixated on that error message at boot and just didn't check prior to Googling and asking the question on here.

Comment: `free` is easier, if you only have one swap. the last line will show Swap: 0 if you don't have it. or Swap: somenumber if you have it. no need for sudo.